# Remove Windows WFP filter that's blocking port 445 SMB traffic - Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, network-share

A customer is having issues reaching a critical Windows 2008R2 server's file shares from most of their internal systems. A quick look shows that the Windows firewall is off, but only a small handful of systems can reach the share.

I tried the normal troubleshooting steps and even went through re-creating virtual network adapters (VMware) and changing IP addresses, clearing mac tables, ARP, etc.

In the end, I discovered a set of filters in the Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) that explicitly blocked port 445 traffic in/out. This may have been the result of Malware at some point, but I'm looking for a way to delete these filters (by filterID) or disable the filtering system entirely.

Here's what I'm seeing: https://pastebin.com/BRhE4sJd

Is this even possible? All I see [online is a C++ API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366504)...

---

Snippet:

```
                <item>
                    <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_IP_LOCAL_PORT</fieldKey>
                    <matchType>FWP_MATCH_EQUAL</matchType>
                    <conditionValue>
                        <type>FWP_UINT16</type>
                        <uint16>445</uint16>
                    </conditionValue>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_IP_PROTOCOL</fieldKey>
                    <matchType>FWP_MATCH_EQUAL</matchType>
                    <conditionValue>
                        <type>FWP_UINT8</type>
                        <uint8>6</uint8>
                    </conditionValue>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_IP_LOCAL_ADDRESS_TYPE</fieldKey>
                    <matchType>FWP_MATCH_EQUAL</matchType>
                    <conditionValue>
                        <type>FWP_UINT8</type>
                        <uint8>1</uint8>
                    </conditionValue>
                </item>
            </filterCondition>
            <action>
                <type>FWP_ACTION_BLOCK</type>
                <filterType/>
            </action>
```

Comment: If you're not depending on the firewall to provide other security, you might try to stop the BFE (Base Filtering Engine) service for a short term fix.  It seems to store some of it config beneath: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\BFE\Parameters\Policy. More risky but you could try deleting those keys.

Comment: I couldn't get the BFE to stop... even setting to manual and rebooting.The registry key didn't seem to have an impact.

Comment: Where did that XML come from? I believe that WFP is indeed just an API for programs to insert themselves within the networking stack; thus, the traffic would actually be blocked by some service or program utilizing WFP. Are there any services running that might be filtering traffic? Are you sure that Windows Firewall is disabled for the network profile (Home, Work, or Public) that the server is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were hit with Cryptocurrency miner malware.  It added SMB TCP 445 blocking in Windows Filtering Platform (WFP).

Run the below commands to list policies and filter lists:

```
netsh ipsec static show filterlist all
netsh ipsec static show policy all
```

Run  these to delete them:

```
netsh ipsec static delete policy all
netsh ipsec static delete filterlist all
```